# How can I delete saved game data off Iphone?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, games, data

I am trying to delete saved game data on my phone for a specific app so that I can start over. Problem is I have tried every way i can find including the icloud storage way. Everytime I redownload the game the saved content still comes back...can anyone help me???

Comment: See if there is some setting in the app itself to purge it.. Instagram had this way of doing things. Also, is the app's name shareable? @becca

Comment: Define "every way." What **exactly** have you done, in detail. I can think of several ways that might fix this issue but don't want to wast time suggesting what has been tried already